# Angular window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' }) not working consistently

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have scroll.service.ts in my Angular project that has scrollToTop method that is supposed to scroll to top smoothly. I have scroll-to-top component that uses this function to scroll to top when clicked and it scrolls smoothly. However, when using in another method in my header component, it does not scroll smooth unless I set this:

```
html { scroll-behavior: smooth; }  /* styles.scss */
```

But the issue is that I cannot set it to smooth, because I need my { scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled' } in my routing file to restore scroll position instantly, without smooth scroll. Logically, since I am using the same function in scroll-to-top component and header component, both should scroll to top smoothly without setting scroll-behavior to smooth in global css styles. What could be the reason?

scroll.service.ts:

```
scrollToTop(): void {
    window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' }); 
}
```

scroll-to-top.component.ts:

```
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { ScrollService } from '../shared/scroll.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-scroll-to-top',
  templateUrl: './scroll-to-top.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./scroll-to-top.component.scss']
})
export class ScrollToTopComponent {
constructor(private scrollService: ScrollService) {}

showScrollToTopButton = false;

@HostListener('window:scroll')
onScroll(): void {
  this.showScrollToTopButton = window.pageYOffset > 30;
}

scrollToTop(): void {
  this.scrollService.scrollToTop();  // it scrolls smoothly
}
```

header.component.ts:

```
onHeaderLinkClick(link: string, drawer: MatSidenav): void {
  const currentUrl = this.router.url;
  const baseUrl = currentUrl.split('/')[1];

  if (baseUrl === link || (baseUrl === '' && link === '/')) {
    drawer.close();
    this.scrollService.scrollToTop(); // it doesn't scroll smoothly even though it's the same function
  }
}
```

Any ideas or suggestions are appreciated!